# How can I return a single Promise[A] given A or Promise[A]?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, promise

I have two functions that are working as expected

1. `def getSomething: Promise[JsValue]`
2. `def getSomethingElse: Promise[JsValue]`

Now I want to define a third function (`def getAll: Promise[JsValue]`) that calls `getSomething` and then based on the response either return the response or `getSomethingElse` and append its response to the original.

I currently have `getAll` defined as follows:

```
def getAll: Promise[JsValue] = {
  getSomething flatMap { response:JsValue =>
    (response \ "someAttribute").asOpt[String] match {
      case None =>
        val resultPromise = Promise[JsValue]
        resultPromise.redeem(response)
        resultPromise
      case Some(someAttribute) => getSomethingElse map { moreResponse:JsValue =>
        response ++ moreResponse
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works but was wondering if there was a shorter way to accomplish the same thing that was more canonical scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a response from Derek Williams on the [cross post on Play Frameworks Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/F3Pnifjcnz8/FZakFeoPgKsJ).

> The only thing I see there that isn't ideal is pattern matching on Option, instead using map/getOrElse gives you a bit more freedom to compose better. Also, if you aren't going to use some value, it's best to not give it a name and instead use _

```
def getAll: Promise[JsValue] = {
  getSomething flatMap { response =>
    (response \ "someAttribute").asOpt[String] map { _ =>
      getSomethingElse map (response ++ _)
    } getOrElse {
      Promise pure response
    }
  }
}
```